# Simple Google Analytics API Algorithm

Tags: api

One of those "urgent needed yesterday" projects has come up and would appreciate input.
We have Google Analytics account with a couple of reports which are in the "customization" section of the reports....

What is the best way to create a program that can pull this information for the reports, but with our code running a loop of dates (we need DAILY reports starting back in 2011) and export this to CSV....

to be more detailed I need the API code to do the following (this is obviously psuedo-algorithm but gets idea across hopefully)

1. Date: aug 2011 (this will be the top of the loop)
2. pull Page views, Pages /visit Visits, Visit Durations metrics
3. Feed custom Variable (this works great in google analytics itself, but I am lost as to how one does this via the API?)

   1. Export to csv
   2. loop again with next date 
      Questions on Solutions
   3. Is Javascript or php a good way to go? if so does anyone have ANY examples/samples of how to do this?
      2.BTW I have downloaded the SDK for asp.net C#... as you all might well know, with this being urgent need, I thought to ask if there is a simpler route I have missed...
   4. Anyone use APp Scripts for something like this, where you can run a routine in a loop to get the spreadsheet/csv info?

Answer (score 1):

solved!
I am working on documenting this insane world of Google analytics that put me through 8 hours of discovering and rediscovering how google expects API calls ...

as a hint I went with a simple .NET solution... once I have it all straight in my head and the project is done, I am documenting it and will update this post!